# How to validate multiple flask forms in a single method?

Tags: python, forms, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am validating three forms in the same method, I was able to validate two out of three forms, but third form is not validating.

```
views.py
......
@main.route('/tournament/<tid>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def tournament(tid):
    ......
    form1 = AddTeamForm()
    form2 = CreateTeamForm()
    form3 = CreateMatchForm()

    # Dynamic allocation of team choices
    team_choices = [(team.id, team.name) for team in tournament.teams]
    form3.team1.choices = team_choices
    form3.team2.choices = team_choices

    if form1.validate_on_submit():
        .....
        return redirect(url_for('main.tournament', tid=tid))

    if form2.validate_on_submit():
        .....
        return redirect(url_for('main.tournament', tid=tid))

    if form3.validate_on_submit():
        print('Passed the validation')
        team1 = Team.query.get(int(form3.team1.data))
        team2 = Team.query.get(int(form3.team2.data))
        match = Match(
            tournment_id=tid,
            name=team1.name+' Vs '+team2.name,
            match_date=form3.match_date.data)
        match.teams.append(team1)
        match.teams.append(team2)
        db.session.add(match)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('main.tournament', tid=tid))

    return render_template(
        'main/tournment.html',
        form1=form1,
        form2=form2,
        form3=form3)

forms.py
....
class CreateMatchForm(FlaskForm):
    team1 = SelectField('Team1',  coerce=int, validators=[DataRequired()])
    team2 = SelectField('Team2',  coerce=int, validators=[DataRequired()])
    match_date = DateField('Match Date', validators=[DataRequired()], 
        render_kw={'type': 'date'},
        default=date.today()+timedelta(days=1))
    submit = SubmitField('Create New Match')


tournment.html
....
<form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('main.tournament', tid=tid) }}">
    {{ form3.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form3.team1(class="form-control m-2")}}
    {{ form3.team1(class="form-control m-2")}}
    {{ form3.match_date(class="form-control m-2")}}
    {{ form3.submit(class="form-control m-2 btn btn-success btn-sm")}}
</form>
```

This is how the UI looks:

[image]

After Post Request:

[image]

It's not even printing the print/error message.

The third form is not validating for any value, so the matches are not creating. I tried to create matches using the same script in flask shell, its perfectly working and the matches are creating, but I was unable to create using this form. How do I get through it?

Comment: does `form2` validate successfuly?

Comment: @janmpeterka Yeah, the names in the blue pills are created using form2.

Comment: they are created, but are they validated? try to pinpoint exact place in your code where things stop to happen as expected.

Comment: @janmpeterka Yes, they are created. After submitting the form3, I'm redirecting back to the same page with the form values as I filled previously and it's not printing any error messages on the command prompt. To check whether the form3 is getting validated or not I placed a print statement as the first line and it's not even printing that. So, may be the form3 is not validating and I don't find any issues for not validating that form.

Comment: If your `print` is not executed, i would guess that this branch of code doest run at all. If form1 or form2 validated sucessfully, it ran redirect, and no code after that (including form3 validation) wa executed.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a temporary solution. Instead of using flask forms I used raw html forms and it worked.

Replaced form3 with request object in views.py:

```
if request.method == "POST":
        print('Passed the validation')
        team1 = Team.query.get(int(request.form['team1']))
        team2 = Team.query.get(int(request.form['team2']))
        match = Match(
            tournament_id=tid,
            name=team1.name+' Vs '+team2.name,
            match_date=request.form['match_date'])
        match.teams.append(team1)
        match.teams.append(team2)
        db.session.add(match)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('main.tournament', tid=tid))
```

Replaced flask forms with raw html forms:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('main.tournment', tid=tid) }}">
    <select class="form-control m-2" id="team1" name="team1" required="">
        {% for team in tournament.teams %}
            <option value={{team.id}}>{{team.name}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <select class="form-control m-2" id="team2" name="team2" required="">
        {% for team in tournament.teams %}
            <option value={{team.id}}>{{team.name}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input class="form-control m-2" type="date" name="match_date" required="">
    <input class="form-control m-2 btn btn-success btn-sm" type="submit" value="Create Match">
</form>
```

Now it is working as expected:

[image]

Still, I am clueless. Why it's not working using flask forms?